# Multi-word synonym search in Solr

Tags: solr, synonym

I'm trying to use a synonym filter to search for a phrase.

```
peter=> spider man, spiderman, Mary Jane, .....
```

I use the default configuration. When I put these synonyms into `synonym.txt` and restart Solr it seems to work only partially: It starts to search for `"spider"`, `"man"`, `"spiderman"`, `"Mary"` and `"Jane"` but what I want to search for are the meaningful combinations - like `"spider man"`, `"Mary Jane"` and `"spiderman"`.

Comment: Just want to point out that solr has added better support for multi term synonyms. See https://lucidworks.com/2017/04/18/multi-word-synonyms-solr-adds-query-time-support/.

Answer (score 5):

Yes sadly this is a well known problem due to how the Solr query parser breaks up on whitespace *before* analyzing. So instead of seeing "spider" before "man" in the token stream, you instead simply see each word on its own. Just "spider" with nothing before/after and just "man" with nothing before/after.

This is because most Solr query forms see a space as basically an "OR". Search for "spider OR man" instead of looking at the full text, analyzing it to generate synonyms, then generating a query from that.

For more background, there's [this blog post](http://opensourceconnections.com/2013/10/27/why-is-multi-term-synonyms-so-hard-in-solr/)

There's a large number of solutions to this problem, including the following:

- [hon-lucene-synonyms](https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms). This plugin runs an analyzer before generating an edismax query over multiple fields. It's a bit of a blackbox, and I've found it can generate some complex query forms that generate weird performance and relevance bugs.
- [Lucidwork's autophrase query parser](https://github.com/lucidworks/auto-phrase-tokenfilter) By selectively autophrasing, this plugin lets you specify key phrases (spider man) that should not be broken into OR queries and can have synonym expansion applied
- OpenSource Connection's [Match query parser](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2017/01/23/our-solution-to-solr-multiterm-synonyms/). Searches a single field using a query-specified analyzer run before the field is searched. Also searches multi-word synonyms as phrases. My favorite, but disclaimer: I'm the author :)
- Rene Kriegler's [Querqy](https://github.com/renekrie/querqy) -- Querqy is a Solr plugin for query preprocessing rules. These rules can identify your key phrases and rewrite the query to non-multiterm form.
- Roll your own: Learn to write your own [query parser plugin](https://dzone.com/articles/create-custom-solr-queryparser) and handle the problem however you want.

Comment: You should also mention the use of special characters and a `PatternReplaceFilterFactory` char (e.g. `spiderman, spider man, peter => peter, spiderman, spider_man` followed by a replacement of `_` with ` `.  It doesn't work in every situation, but it does work in quite a few.
(Stolen from the same blog post that mentions your Match query parser.)

Answer (score 4):

My usually strategy for this kind of problem is to use the synonym filter not to expand a search to include all of the possible synonyms, but to normalize to a single form. I do this **both** in my index and query field analysis.

For example, with this line in my `fieldType/analyzer` block in `schema.xml`:

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
```

(Note the `expand="false"`)
...and this line in my `synonyms.txt`:

```
spiderman, spider man, Mary Jane => peter
```

This way I make sure that any of these four values will be indexed *and* searched as "peter". For example, if the source document mentions "The Amazing Spider Man" it will be indexed as "The Amazing peter". When a user searches for "Mary Jane" it will search for "peter" instead, so it **will match**.

The important thing here is that because "Mary" is not one of the comma-separated synonyms, it won't be changed if it appears without "Jane" following. So searching for "Mary is amazing" will actually search for "Mary is amazing", and it will not match the document.

One of the important details, is that I choose a normalized form (e.g. "peter") that is only one word. I could organize it this way:

```
peter, spiderman, spider man => Mary Jane
```

but because Mary Jane is two words, it may (depending on other features of my search), match the two words separately as well as together. By choosing a single word form to normalize into, I make sure that my tokenizer won't try to break it up.

Comment: Thanks for info(although I may need more time to understand this), one thing I can not do is reindex all documents any more. I can only edit the synonym.txt and restart the SOLR

Comment: Ah. Then you will not be able to apply the normalization at index time, and that's an important part of my strategy. Lacking that, there are fewer options. It might help to make more of your searches as explicit phrase searches. In other words, instead of searching for `peter`, try searching for `"peter"`. This isn't ideal, since you may not _want_ to use phrase searching all of the time, but it may help you in some cases when you can include the quotation marks.

Comment: As this gets tokenized before the filter factory is applied, wouldn't 'spider' and 'man' be two different tokens? In which case 'spider man' wouldn't ever match the token provided to the filter. Looking at [Solr Doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-SynonymFilter) this says: _This filter does synonym mapping. Each token is looked up in the list of synonyms and if a match is found, then the synonym is emitted in place of the token. The position value of the new tokens are set such they all occur at the same position as the original token._

Answer (score 1):

It's a known limitation within Solr / Lucene. Essentially you would have to provide an alternative form of tokenization so that specific space delimited words (i.e. phrases) are treated as single words.
One way of achieving this is to do this client side - i.e. in your application that is calling Solr, when indexing, keep a list of synonym phrases and find / replace those phrase values with an alternative (for example removing the spaces or replacing it with a delimiter that isn't treated as a token boundary).

E.g. if you have "Hello There" as a phrase you want to use in a synonym, then replace it with "HelloThere" when indexing.

Now in your synonyms.txt file you can have (for example):

```
Hi HelloThere Wotcha => Hello
```

Similarly when you search, replace any incidences of "Hello There" in the query string with HelloThere and then they will be matched as a synonym of Hello.

Alternatively, you could use the [AutoPhraseTokenFilter](https://github.com/lucidworks/auto-phrase-tokenfilter) that LucidWorks created, available on github. This works by maintaining a token stream so that it can work out if a combination of two or more sequential tokens matches one of the synonym phrases, and if it doesn't, it throws away the first token as not matching the phrase. I'm not sure how much overhead this adds, but it seems a good approach - would be nice to have by default in Solr as part of the SynonymFilter.