# Multi term solr synonym issue

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene

I have defined synonyms as below :
`facebook,fb,face book, face bk`

Now when I search for facebook the parsed query is

```
<str name="parsedquery_toString">
    text:facebook text:fb text:face text:face text:book text:bk
</str>
```

But if I search for face book, then the parsed query is

```
<str name="parsedquery_toString">
    text:face text:book
</str>
```

Shouldn't the parsed query be the same for both the keywords?

This is snippet of my config :

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>       
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Please find the contents of the synonym.txt

```
#some test synonym mappings unlikely to appear in real input text
aaafoo => aaabar
bbbfoo => bbbfoo bbbbar
cccfoo => cccbar cccbaz
fooaaa,baraaa,bazaaa

# Some synonym groups specific to this example
GB,gib,gigabyte,gigabytes
MB,mib,megabyte,megabytes
facebook,fb,face book, face bk
Television, Televisions, TV, TVs
#notice we use "gib" instead of "GiB" so any WordDelimiterFilter coming
#after us won't split it into two words.

# Synonym mappings can be used for spelling correction too
pixima => pixma
```

Comment: I hate to duplicate information, but this answer lists a number of various solutions to the problem

http://stackoverflow.com/a/41837371/8123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a well known issue in Solr/Lucene, you can find more about it in:

- [the lucene ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4499)
- [this blog post](http://nolanlawson.com/2012/10/31/better-synonym-handling-in-solr/), see the part titled **Multi-word synonyms won’t be matched in queries**

If you want to fix this, you have several options:

1. apply one of the several plugings/parsers mentioned in the above two resources. As a downside, you will have to redo the work everytime you upgrade solr etc.
2. move synonyms to the index time. This is preferred anyway, although it has its own downsides.